# Show the GUI button when mouse hover to the object

Tags: c#, unity, turn-based

i already have this player on my screen. And i want, whenever the mouse hover at the object, the GUI button show itself (like tooltip). I tried below code, but the button is not showed up when i hover at the object. Here is my code:

```
void OnMouseEnter()

    {

        Rect buttonRect = new Rect(250, Screen.height - buttonHeight, textInfoPlayerButtonWidth, textInfoPlayerButtonHeight);



        if (GameManager.instance.currentPlayerIndex == 0) (the object)

        {

            if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "This is player 1"))

            {



            }

        }

    }
```

I want to be like this:

[image]

But i want it to be show that GUI hovering button on that character, not when the character selected.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can only call GUI functions inside `void OnGUI()`. So, make a boolean to indicate when the mouse is hovering on a character and flag that bool as true. Then in the `OnGUI` you have that tooltip wrapped:

```
void OnGUI()
{
    if(showCharToolTip)
    {  
                if (GUI.Button(buttonRect, "This is player 1"))
                {
                }
    }
}
```